# bootstrapping angular with ng-view and router

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

It's not an app with ng-app in the body, it's angular.bootstrap application and for some reason I can't make it work with ng-router.

**Anyone has an experience using router with angular.bootstrap?**

I'm using [angular bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap) on a dom element and trying to access the $router parameters

**DOM**

```
 <ul class="timeline" id="list" ng-controller="Controller" ng-view style="display: none">
```

**Angularjs**

```
var self = this;

angular.module(this.constructor.NAME, ["ngRoute"]) //ng-view, ng-controller
        .controller("Controller", ["$scope", "$element", "$routeProvider", function($scope, $element, $routeProvider){
             self.controller($scope, $element, $routeProvider)
         }]
);

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("list"), [this.constructor.NAME]);
```

**Controller**

```
controller: function($scope, $element, $routeProvider) {
    console.log($scope); //$scope is fine
    console.log($routeProvider); 
    console.log($element); //works if ng-view is not defined attr on <ul>
},
```

**Is ng-view really required?** I don't need `ng-view` on `ul` but I guess it was required to get the route work, I can work without it. All I need is router and params.

**ng-cloak** I used `display: none` style because `ng-cloak` sucks, I manually remove it when data is ready. any comments.

**Question:**

how can I make it all work together so I get `$scope, $element and $routeProvider`

**Edit**

I realized I should be using config. So I updated the code a bit but still no $routeProvider

```
angular.module(this.constructor.NAME, ["ngRoute"]) //ng-view, ng-controller
    .config(["$routeProvider"], function($routeProvider){
         console.log($routeProvider) //throwing error
     })
     .controller("Controller", ["$scope", "$element", function($scope, $element){self.controller($scope, $element)}]);

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("list"), [this.constructor.NAME]);
```

**Dependencies**

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want $routeParams to get parameters.  This how I typically set up my apps.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/admin/:pizza?', { //in this case, you would use $routeParams.pizza
        controller: 'homeController',
        templateUrl: '/views/whatever.html',
        caseInsensitiveMatch: true
    })
    .otherwise({
        controller: 'homeController',
        templateUrl: '/views/index.html'
    })
}]);
```

And then in my controller

```
(function(){

    var homeController = function ($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope, $routeParams){   
        $rootScope.path = $location.path();
        $scope.pizza = $routeParams.pizza;
    };

    homeController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$rootScope', '$routeParams'];
    app.controller('homeController', homeController);    

}());
```

This would make domain.com/#/admin/34353 make `$scope.pizza` equal to 34353.  You can also chain as many parameters as you'd like, `.when('/admin/:pizza?/:betterPizza?'`.

The question mark after the parameter makes it nullable.

Comment: Can you please make it work with `angular.bootstrap`, that's what I'm using to trigger apps, I don't have ng-app in the body, I've this in my question, bootstrapping angular with router